# Craft 3 validate new password in change password

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, users, password

I'm trying to validate user's new password and confirm password in my custom plugin `init()`.

```
Event::on(User::class, User::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE, function(Event $event) {
    $formData = $_POST;
    $newPassword =  $formData['newPassword'];
    $confirmPassword =  $formData['confirmPassword'];

    if ($newPassword != $confirmPassword){
        Craft::$app->session->setError('Confirm password does not match new password');
    }
});
```

On the template:

```
{% set error = craft.app.session.getFlash('error') %}
{% if error|length > 0 %}
    {{error}}
{% endif %}
```

The problem with this is, it displays the message "Confirm password does not match new password" on frontend but the password gets changed into `newPassword` value. Is there a way to stop processing any further after returning error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
if ($newPassword != $confirmPassword){
    Craft::$app->session->setError('Confirm password does not match new password');
    $event->isValid = false;
}
```

Setting `isValid` to false will stop further processing of that element (the user in this case).